# Link my tag on other website search

Tags: php, search, hyperlink, tags

This is my search code

```
<div id="search">
    <form method="get" action="http://www.other-website.com/search">
        <input type="hidden" name="f" value="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Temukan informasi, komunitas & produk yang kamu cari disini" accesskey="s" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the tag code (display only text "do not link")

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' ';
  }
}
?>
```

The code can apply well on the website, but I have to enter text to the search. I just want to place my tag on that search text

so my question is
How to make fixed word(my tag) automatically placed on search or where I must place the tag code, the search result is mytag linked on @www.other-website.com/search so user do not have to type? I want to search my tag on other website search

Comment: I do not understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a night try & errorr, I think I've found it, and here is the details of the code :

```
<?php 
$posttags = get_the_tags(); 
if ($posttags) { 
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $tag_link = 'http://xxx.orhersite.xxx';
        echo "<a href='$tag_link/$tag->name'>";
        echo "$tag->name";
    }
} ?>
```

that can direct to the other website search xxx.othersite.xxx/search/my-tag
but now other problem show that if user clicks on that link, it opened at the same page.
I've tried

```
echo "<a href onclick="window.open('');

<?php 
$posttags = get_the_tags(); 
if ($posttags) { 
    foreach($posttags as $tag) { 
        $tag_link = 'http://xxx.orhersite.xxx';
        echo "<a href onclick="window.open('$tag_link/$tag->name')">";
        echo "$tag->name";
    }
} ?>
```

How to open the link to the new tab using onClick on that code?

Comment: Have you got the answer? and for the new tab `<a target="">`

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is taking the value from the textbox where you enter the search query and using `onsubmit()` create a javascript function 
`var searchkeyword=document.forms["formname"]["textboxname/id"].value;`
`window.location("www.othersite.com/"+searchkeyword);`

Comment: @ ganeshrj thanks, how do you apply yours on mine, sorry cause I don't experienced on coding. :)

Comment: please send me your code what you have done.So that I can give suggestions.

Comment: <?php 
$posttags = get_the_tags(); 
if ($posttags) { 
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $tag_link = 'http://xxx.orhersite.xxx';
        echo "<a href='$tag_link/$tag->name'>";
        echo "$tag->name";
    }
} ?>